# Python - непростое получение всех возможных комбинаций

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеются дома: *h1, h2, h3, и т.д.*

Имеются жители: *p1, p2, p3, и т.д.*

Нужно составить следующий список:

```
[
({h1: [p1]},
 {h2: [p2]},
 {h3: [p3]}
),
({h1: [p1, p2]},
 {h2: [p3]},
 {h3: []}
),
({h1: [p1, p2, p3]},
 {h2: []},
 {h3: []}
),
...
]
```

То есть, создать все возможные комбинации распределения жителей в домах.
Сам не смог решить такую задачку, поможете?

Comment: Покажите нам, пожалуйста, что вы пока сделали.

Comment: на каком именно месте не смог? покажи что уже получилось

Comment: уже всё смог, ответ ниже :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался с вопросом

```
import itertools

p = ["p1", "p2", "p3"]
h = ["h1", "h2", "h3"]
r   = list(itertools.product(p, h))
res = list(itertools.combinations(r, len(p)))

print(res)
```

Возвращает:

```
(('p1', 'h1'), ('p1', 'h2'), ('p1', 'h3'))
(('p1', 'h1'), ('p1', 'h2'), ('p2', 'h1'))
(('p1', 'h1'), ('p1', 'h2'), ('p2', 'h2'))
(('p1', 'h1'), ('p1', 'h2'), ('p2', 'h3'))
...
```

А из этого нетрудно сделать нужный список

Answer (score 0):

Каждый из жителей может быть в одном из `N` домов, т.е. у него есть `N` вариантов. А у `M` жителей - `N^M` вариантов.

Таким образом, остаётся представить числа от `0` до `N^M-1` включительно в N-ричной системе счисления (например, с помощью целочисленного деления `//` и операции модуля `%`), каждое число соответствует определённому распределению жильцов.

Comment: спасибо, уже разобрался